# Unicode to CP 0 conversion in Winedit

Tags: winedt, newunicodechar

I am writing a report in latex using Winedt 7.0 editor. The language of the write-up is in two languages, in English and in Chinese. For the English there is no problem and it compiles well. But when I put the Chinese characters and tries to save the .tex file it shows the following error

*

Some Characters were lost while converting from UNICODE to CP 0. Save the file anyway?

*

If I save the file anyway and compile the output shows ?? in place of Chinese characters.
Please guide me how can I fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have to convert your file from UTF to CP encoding?

Comment: I am unaware of how to perform CP conversion. I searched over internet but did not resolved. Will you please guide me how I can make the conversions?. Thanks

Comment: You need  imho a newer winedt. I don't think that winedt 7 could already handle utf8 fully.