# Unicode to CP 0 conversion

Tags: input-encodings, winedt

I am writing a report in TeX using Winedt 8.1 editor. The language of the write-up is in two languages, in English and in Russian. For the English there is no problem and it compiles well. But when I put the Russian  characters and tries to save the .tex file it shows the following error

Some Characters were lost while converting from UNICODE to CP 0. Save the file anyway?

if I save the file anyway and compile the output shows ?? in place of Russian characters. Please guide me how can I fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should save your file as utf8 not in 8bit (I don't remember if winedt 8.1 could do 8.1 but I think yes).

Comment: This is identical to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476091/80972